# Controlando para evitar que janela seja aberta novamente no MDIForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Como verifico se uma janela foi aberta? Caso tenha sido aberta, trazer-la para frente, caso contrario, abrir uma nova janela. Ou seja, necessito controlar as janelas, verificando-as para que somente uma esteja aberta.

Comment: Explique melhor o que você quer saber. Você quer controlar para que somente uma instância da aplicação seja aberta?

Comment: http://sanity-free.org/143/csharp_dotnet_single_instance_application.html

Answer (score 1):

Fácil.
No evento onde está neste momento a abrir a janela, coloque a seguinte condição:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim fEncontrou As Boolean = False
    For Each f As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If f.Name = "Form2" Then
            fEncontrou = True
            f.BringToFront()
            f.Activate()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If Not fEncontrou Then Form2.Show()
End Sub
```